# Algorithm - Upgrade Buckets and Pour Water into Vats Problem

Tags: algorithm

The problem [here](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/o8SXZn/) from LeetCode:

> LCP 33. Pouring Water into Vats
> There are N originally empty vats with infinite capacity, everyone of which has a corresponding bucket. `i`-th bucket has a capacity of `bucket[i]`. There are 2 kinds of operations:
>
> - Upgrade a bucket: choose a bucket and increment its capacity by `1`
> - Pour water into vats： fill all buckets full of water and pour all water into corresponding vat
>
> Every vat has a minimum demand. `i`-th vat has a demand of `vat[i]`. Return the minimum number of operations to meet demands of all vats. (The demand of a vat is fulfilled if actual amount of water is greater than or equal to the demand.)
>
> - Example 1:
>   Input: bucket = [1, 3], vat = [6, 8]
>   Output: 4
>   Illustration: First upgrade `0`-th bucket. For the rest 3 operations, pour water into vats.
> - Example 2:
>   Input: bucket = [9, 0, 1], vat = [0, 2, 2]
>   Output: 3
>   Illustration: First upgrade `1`-th bucket. For the rest 2 operations, pour water into vats.

I want to know whether this is an NP hard problem and what is the best algorithm to solve it.
Blogs said that upgrade-bucket operations should be done ahead of pour-water operations.
Solutions I found was to traverse by number of operations of pouring water into vats. That is, traverse all possible number of operations of pouring water into vats, compute the number of operations and record the minimum. [This](https://blog.csdn.net/zml66666/article/details/115705450) is one of them. I had a similar solution that passed all the tests. But I don't know whether it is the best. I don't even know whether it is correct because the tests may be insufficient.
I traverse through all possible number of operations of pouring water into vats but stop when the number of operations become bigger than last result. My C++ code is as follows.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Solution {
public:
    int storeWater(std::vector<int>& bucket, std::vector<int>& vat) {
        int number_of_restore = 0;  // Number of pour-water operations
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.size(); i++) {  // Initialize number of pour-water operations
            number_of_restore = std::max(static_cast<int>(std::ceil(static_cast<float>(vat.at(i)) / (bucket.at(i)? bucket.at(i) : 1))), number_of_restore);
        }
        if (!number_of_restore) {
            return 0;
        }

        while (true) {
            long long total_cost = number_of_restore;
            for (int i = 0; i < bucket.size(); i++) {
                total_cost += std::max(static_cast<int>(std::ceil(static_cast<float>(vat.at(i)) / number_of_restore) - bucket.at(i)), 0);
            }
            if (number_of_restore <= 1) {
                return total_cost;
            }
            long long total_cost_try = 0;
            int number_of_restore_try = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bucket.size(); i++) {
                int number_of_enlarge = std::max(static_cast<int>(std::ceil(static_cast<float>(vat.at(i)) / (number_of_restore - 1)) - bucket.at(i)), 0);
                total_cost_try += number_of_enlarge;
                number_of_restore_try = std::max(static_cast<int>(std::ceil(static_cast<float>(vat.at(i)) / (number_of_enlarge + bucket.at(i)))), number_of_restore_try);
            }
            total_cost_try += number_of_restore_try;
            if (total_cost_try <= total_cost) {
                number_of_restore = number_of_restore_try;
            } else {
                return total_cost;  // Stop traversal
            }
        }
    }
};
```